# How to write expression in java8?

Tags: java-8

I'm trying to write this function with java 8 , but i didn't succeeded.
This is my code :

```
private LocalTime getAbsenceParJour(List<test> tests) {
    LocalTime absenceParJourTime = null;
    Duration sum = Duration.ZERO;
    for (test perPrestation : tests) {
        if (perPrestation.getTypeContactLibre().equalsIgnoreCase("absence")) {
            Duration duration = Duration.between(perPrestation.getHeureDebut(), perPrestation.getHeureFin());
            sum = sum.plus(duration);
        }
    }
    if (sum != null) {
        long m = sum.toMinutes() % 60;
        long s = sum.toHours() % 60;
        absenceParJourTime = LocalTime.of(Long.valueOf(s).intValue(), Long.valueOf(m).intValue());
    }
    return absenceParJourTime;
}
```

where test is a class java this is :

```
public class Prestation {
   private LocalTime heureDebut;
   private LocalTime heureFin;
   private String typeContactLibre;
}
```

Any help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private LocalTime getAbsenceParJour(List<test> tests) {
    Duration sum = tests.stream()
        .filter(P-> P.getTypeContactLibre().equalsIgnoreCase("absence"))
        .reduce(null, (sum, p) ->
            (sum == null ? Duration.ZERO : sum)
              .plus(Duration.between(p.getHeureDebut(), p.getHeureFin()));
    LocalTime absenceParJourTime = null;
    if (sum != null) {
        int m = (int)(sum.toMinutes() % 60);
        int s = (int)(sum.toHours() % 60);
        absenceParJourTime = LocalTime.of(s, m);
    }
    return absenceParJourTime;
}
```

Use of Stream is tricky here:

- There is a `.sum` but not for `Duration`. So you must use `reduce`.
- You want to distinguish between a Duration.ZERO found, and nothing found.

For durations I think you could do without the use of null.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you're asking to replace your foreach with java8 then below is syntax :

```
 tests.stream().forEach(tests -> {
        if (perPrestation.getTypeContactLibre().equalsIgnoreCase("absence")) {
            Duration duration = Duration.between(perPrestation.getHeureDebut(), perPrestation.getHeureFin());
            sum = sum.plus(duration);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That is just replacing a single for each with a foreach lambda. A real java 8 stream solution would be filter + map + sum

Comment: @Umesh Sulakude with filter +map +sum

Comment: Let me try for that.